# Abilities that slow interaction with oppressor

Tags: league-of-legends

When I am playing volibear and I activate majestic roar, an ability what deals damage and slows, will the damage or the slow be applied first? This matters to me since this could be very beneficial or not with the mastery [oppressor](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Oppressor_%28Season_2016_Mastery%29).

> Grants 2.5% increased damage against units with impaired movement (airborne, slow, stun, snare, taunt, suppression).

Will the damage of volibears majestic roar be increased or just the attack that follows after the enemy is already slowed?

Comment: Out of interest, is that 2.5% increased damage from all sources? attacks, abilities, passives and actives? It doesn't state attacks, so I would assume so?

Comment: Any damage the target would take (before resistances) is increased by 2.5%. It's benefitial to take this on a Champion who won't get many kills or has easy to apply CC. At least when compared to its contempart of 1% per different Champion Killed

Comment: @nickson104 I forgot to tag you, my apologies

Comment: @Oak if you go for ferocity anyways, in most cases oppressor is better because it just gives you a good boost in the early game because the stats are instant and in case to make Bounty Hunter worth it you need at least 3 kills to make it better..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When an ability hits an enemy, the game calculates the result. In this case, it would calculate the Champion's new movementspeed, and the Champion's new Current Health.

This means that they are applied at the same time, and as such it **will not** make opressor trigger with the same skill. In other words, the target needs to be under Crowd Control before the Opressor triggers, even if the ability you use has CC in it.

Comment: However note that Volibear has several ways to apply slows (and one displacement). You can just as well chain them for similar damage.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experiences, i believe the damage is applied first, since the slow effect is only applied IF it hits the enemy, therefore it will first apply the damage, then the slow, meaning opressor will only help you deal more damage on the next hits.

I will test it later this evening to be sure, but for now this is how i believe it works.

Comment: Answer might be right but the logic is wrong: sure, the slow is only applied if the ability hits the enemy, but the damage is also only dealt if the ability hits the enemy.